# Find out the fourth day from a n strtotime date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a strtotime date in a variable. I need to find out the 4th day from that variable

```
$strtotime1=strtotime('06/17/2012');
```

I need to find out the 4th day (i.e.  06/21/2012) in strtotime format.

I have tried with:

```
$strtotime2=$strtotime1+4*60 * 60;
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding 4 hours not 4 days.

It should be `$strtotime2=$strtotime1+4*24*60*60;`

Or

You could do like:

```
$strtotime2 = strtotime('+4 days', $strtotime1);
$date2 = date('m/d/Y', $strtotime2);
```